# Jenkins No JDK named ‘JDK8’ found

Tags: java, jenkins

So I have a bunch of jenkins builds that I have working.. But i'm getting this weird error at the end of my builds.

```
No JDK named ‘JDK8’ found
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
No JDK named ‘JDK8’ found
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I know I have JDK 8 installed on my slave

```
[jenkins@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)
[jenkins@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$
```

It's strange to me that the builds would work? I guess it's not a huge issue but it'd be nice to know why they would work but i'd be getting this issue? I don't have access to global configuration if that makes a difference?

Comment: maybe it's looking for the oracle or EE jdk and not the openjdk